# Python: How to Remove range of Characters \x91\x87\xf0\x9f\x91\x87 from File

Tags: python-3.x

I have this file with some lines that contain some unicode literals like:
 "b'Who\xe2\x80\x99s he?\n\nA fan rushed the field to join the Cubs\xe2\x80\x99 celebration after Jake Arrieta\xe2\x80\x99s no-hitter."

I want to remove those xe2\x80\x99 like characters.

I can remove them if I declare a string that contains these characters but my solutions don't work when reading from a CSV file. I used pandas to read the file.

SOLUTIONS TRIED
1.Regex
2.Decoding and Encoding
3.Lambda

1. Regex Solution

```
line =  "b'Who\xe2\x80\x99s he?\n\nA fan rushed the field to join the Cubs\xe2\x80\x99 celebration after Jake Arrieta\xe2\x80\x99s no-hitter."
code = (re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r'', line))
print (code)
```

2. LAMBDA SOLUTION

```
stripped = lambda s: "".join(i for i in s if 31 < ord(i) < 127)
code2 = stripped(line)
print(code2)
```

3. ENCODING SOLUTION

```
code3 = (line.encode('ascii', 'ignore')).decode("utf-8")
print(code3)
```

HOW FILE WAS READ

```
df = pandas.read_csv('file.csv',encoding = "utf-8")
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(stripped(row['text']))
    print(re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r'', row['text']))
    print(row['text'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')).decode("utf-8"))
```

SUGGESTED METHOD

```
df = pandas.read_csv('file.csv',encoding = "utf-8")

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    en = row['text'].encode()
    print(type(en))
    newline = en.decode('utf-8')
    print(type(newline))
    print(repr(newline))
    print(newline.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
    print(newline.encode('ascii', 'replace'))
```

Comment: Your supposed binary string `line =  "b'Who\xe2\x80\x99s he?..."` is actually not one. Change it to `line =  b'Who\xe2\x80\x99s he?...'`.

Comment: The brackets in the last row of your 'How file was read' section don't match up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string is valid `utf-8`. Therefore it can be directly converted to a python string.

You can then encode it to `ascii` with [str.encode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode). It can ignore non-ascii characters with `'ignore'`.

Also possible: `'replace'`

```py
line_raw =  b'Who\xe2\x80\x99s he?'

line = line_raw.decode('utf-8')
print(repr(line))

print(line.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
print(line.encode('ascii', 'replace'))
```

```
'Who’s he?'
b'Whos he?'
b'Who?s he?'
```

To come back to your original question, your 3rd method was correct. It was just in the wrong order.

```py
code3 = line.decode("utf-8").encode('ascii', 'ignore')
print(code3)
```

To finally provide a working pandas example, here you go:

```py
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv', encoding="utf-8")
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['text'].encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
```

There is no need to do `decode('utf-8')`, because pandas does that for you.

Finally, if you have a python string that contains non-ascii characters, you can just strip them by doing

```py
text = row['text'].encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
```

This converts the text to ascii bytes, strips all the characters that cannot be represented as ascii, and then converts back to text.

You should look up the difference between python3 strings and bytes, that should clear things up for you, I hope.

Comment: Your code works as it but still doesn't work after reading the data from a file.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't connect it correctly to the file reading, then. I could help you if you would show me your code?

Comment: I added the code above under the suggested method title. You will see that I encoded the text first before decoding. If I try to decode first, I get an error saying str has no method decode. Encoding first converts the string to the Bytes class. Thanks for all you help so far.

Comment: Still no, why would you do `en = row['text'].encode()` and then `newline = en.decode('utf-8')`? `encode()` converts from text to utf-8 binary, and `decode('utf-8')` converts from utf-8 binary to text. You can combine those two lines to simply do `newline = row['text']`

Comment: default strings, represented as `'abcd'` are python internal representations of text and can hold *all* characters that exist. That is what pandas returns, your `row['text']` is already in python internal representation, and all unicode characters are correct.
If you then want to store that string as ascii, you need to strip out all non-ascii characters. Which you do with `ascii_bytes = row['text'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')`. You then have a bytes array with ascii encoding, commonly displayed as `b'text'`. The `b'` indicates that it is a bytes-string.

Comment: You then have to look if your csv library / file access needs bytes or python strings as inputs, depending on that you can either directly use `ascii_bytes`, or you have to convert it back to python string with `ascii_bytes.decode('ascii')`

Comment: Nonetheless, you are getting the correct idea now I think :) Feel free to mark my answer as correct if you are satisfied :)