# How to convert one particular text column in data-frame to 'utf-8' using python3

Tags: python-3.x, ascii

I have a dataframe which multiple columns and one column contains **scraped** text from various links.
I tried to convert that column to `utf-8` but it didn't work.

Here is my approach:

```
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',encoding=sys.getfilesystemencoding())
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: x.encode('utf-8').strip())
print(df['text'])
```

I get text with some ascii code :

b"b'#Thank you, it\xe2\x80\x99s good to be ...

```
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',encoding=sys.getfilesystemencoding())
df['text'] = df['text']
print(df['text'])
```

I get the text:

b'#Thank you, it\xe2\x80\x99s good to be here....

```
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8').strip())
```

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

I tried 2-3 approaches but it didn't work. Any alternative?

Using Python 3.6 and jupyter notebook.

Comment: What do you get if you skip the line `df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: x.encode('utf-8').strip())`? Also if you just put `df['text']` as the last line in a cell in both cases what do you see?

Comment: Updated the question above

Comment: as it is bytes, you should not encode but decode it : `b"#Thank you, it\xe2\x80\x99s good".decode("utf-8")`  gives `'#Thank you, it’s good'`

Comment: df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8').strip())  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: Does the first one really show `b"b'#Thank you` at the start? The double-b's are there?

Comment: yes it shows same

Comment: @Wayne any solution?

Comment: Also, I really think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56564419/8508004) described a very similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you wrote for the example where the second line is `df['text'] = df['text']` ends in `'`. In other words, `b'#Thank you, it\xe2\x80\x99s good to be here....'`:

For some reason you have byte code that has been cast to a string because you see `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'` when you try to decode it. (Ideally, it would be best to have not gotten into this situation, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56564419/8508004) for some advice that looks to be pertinent. Alas, going with what you have ... )
I think at this point you can remove the `b'` at the start of the string and `'` at the end far end and [typecast back to byte code](https://techtutorialsx.com/2018/02/04/python-converting-string-to-bytes-object/). Note that this will result in the backslashes getting escaped, and so that needs be dealt with, in addition to now decoding the byte code to a string in the proper way. Using an approach based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37059682/8508004) you can escape and decode the byte code.

Putting this together (sort of like how @rolf82 illustrated in the comments) with what you show as `df['text']`, when `df['text'] = df['text']` and that it is a string at the start, the conversion from what you have would be like this:

```py
a = "b'#Thank you, it\xe2\x80\x99s good to be here'"
# But we only want the parts between the ''.
s = bytes(r"#Thank you, it\xe2\x80\x99s good to be here","utf-8")
import codecs
print(codecs.escape_decode(s)[0].decode("utf-8"))
```

That gives:

```
#Thank you, it’s good to be here
```

Which is what we want.

Now integrating that with Pandas is going to require something extra because we cannot simply say this is a raw string by adding `r` in front. Based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58309907/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2428132/8508004), it seems using `r` in front to cast to raw string can be replaced with `.encode('unicode-escape').decode()`, like:

```py
"#Thank you, it\xe2\x80\x99s good to be here".encode('unicode-escape').decode()
```

So pulling it all together I'd replace your second line with this:

```py
import codecs
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: codecs.escape_decode(bytes(x[2:-1].encode('unicode-escape').decode(), "utf-8"))[0].decode('utf-8').strip())
```

---

If that doesn't work, also try leaving off the `.decode()` after `.encode('unicode-escape')`, which is:

````
```python
import codecs
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: codecs.escape_decode(bytes(x[2:-1].encode('unicode-escape'), "utf-8"))[0].decode('utf-8').strip())
````